# JavaScript how to get this html to read this CSS and organise my script into the table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

How it looks:

[image]

How I want it to look:

[image]

I have a CSS file that has a table all organised and ready my question is how do I get my script to use the table in the CSS file this is my CSS file:

```
/*
    styles.css
*/

body{
    background-color:#cecece;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:1em;
}
h1{
    color:#FF8000;
    text-align:center;
}
table{
    width:95%;
}
caption{
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin:10px;
    color:#FF8000;
}
th{
    width:33.333%;
    font-size:1.1em;
    text-align:left;
    color:steelblue;
}
#output{
    position:absolute;
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
    top:15%;
    left:25%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:.9em;
    background-color:#2E2E2E;
    color:ivory;
}
```

this is my Html document that calls the css and my script

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Student Grades - [Your Name]</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Student Grades System</h1>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script src="./assignment.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript that prints everything out if u need more of the script let me know

```
            var mytable = "<table><caption>Grading Results</caption>";
            document.write(mytable);
            document.write('<td><tr><th>' + "Student"+'</th><th>' +  "Mark!" + '</th><th>'+"Grade" + '</th> </tr></td>');
            for(var i = 0; i < markArr.length; i++){
            document.write(' <tr><td>'+studentArr[i] + space1+markArr[i] + space1+gradeAwarded[i] + '</td> </th> ');
            }
            document.write(' </tr>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "The Highest mark was : "+max+ ''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>' + "The Lowest mark was : "+min+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "The Average mark was : "+average+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>' + "number A grades : "+A+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "number B grades : "+B+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "number C grades : "+C+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('<td>'+ "number F grades : "+F+''+'</td> </th>');
            document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: I don't actually uderstand the question here. What do you mean by scrip using your table?

Comment: Maybe, instead of document.write, use jQuery.append() or create new String and use yourtable.innerHTML = str;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add the code below before the **for** loop:

```
document.write('<table><caption>My Caption</caption>');
```

and this after the loop:

```
document.write('</table>');
```

The problem you told me happened because the `<div>` was closed before the `<table>` was created. Try this:

```
<div id="output">
       <script src="./assignment.js"></script>
</div>
```

together with my code above.

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

A HTML table generally has the format

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Header1</th>
<th>Header2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item1Row1</td>
<td>Item1Row2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Item2Row1</td>
<td>Item2Row2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Try creating a variable and build the html object as a string, then adding it to a element.
something like this:

```
var myTable= "<table><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>Col Head 1</td>";
    myTable+= "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 2</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Col Head 3</td></tr></table>";    

 document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = myTable
```

Comment: +1, but this script won't work in the OP's situation as is. I presume the OP wants to write to the div with id `output`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add the code below before the `for` loop:

```
var mytable = "<table><caption>My Caption</caption>";
```

and this after the loop:

```
document.write(mytable +'</table>');
```

Answer (score 0):

@HelloWorld, here you go. Click on CSS and JavaScript tabs to see how I set it up

http://jsbin.com/cogux/1/edit?html,output

Without knowing what `assignment.js` does, the main steps would be:

1. Create/compile a data set you can loop through
2. Dynamically create the table rows and data
3. Create the statistics area for top student, marks and number of grades (just refer to how I set up #2)
4. Insert table into a target element. In the case for #2 the target was the `<tbody>` element

I hope this helps.

[image: Screenshot]